# store.loadRecords only puts last record in store

Tags: sproutcore

I am putting together my first Sproutcore app. I have a simple model, a controller and a view. When I add a new record using *store.createRecord()* or *.createRecords()* they get added to the store, the controller and the view.

However, when I try to add new records via store.loadRecords() (from a remote source) from the response (e.g.  *[{"name":"test1"},{"name":"test2"},{"name":"test3"}]*), only the last of the records (test3 in this case) ends up in the store. How can I change store.loadRecords() to actually add all the records?

Comment: The problem is the same when I use loadRecords() on the command line.

Comment: The length of the returned array from loadRecords() also shows the correct number.

Comment: If you haven't already, can you verify that they're in the store at all? I wonder if they're getting added to the store correctly but not showing up in the rest of the app for some reason.

Comment: Found the problem: I did not define the primaryKey in the Model. "primaryKey: 'id'," As easy as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: I did not define the primaryKey in the Model. "primaryKey: 'id'," As easy as that.